# Transform a python file, that uses packages like pandas, to be usable by someone that has no python environment

Tags: python

I have a client for whom I have created a program that utilizes a variety of data and machine learning packages. The client would like for the program to be easily run without installing any type of python environment. Is this possible?

I am assuming the best bet would be to transform the .py file into a .exe file but am unsure of how to do this if I have packages that need to be installed before the program can be run.

Are there websites that exist that allow you to easily host complex .py files on them to be run by anyone that accesses the URL?

Comment: you can create executable by using pyinstaller, just read the docs here https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ pip install pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for "freezing", which package everything including the interpreter, libs and packages into a single executable file.
There are several tools for this purpose:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze

https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of [colaboratory](/questions/tagged/colaboratory) that is cloud service provided by Google might be better. Your client who has to sign up for Google account can not only run the python program, but also utilize any major python packages on the cloud (of course, it's possible to install the necessary packages into the client's cloud space), without constructing the python environment on client's local PC. What's more, it's at free!